# Why does pusher in a service worker disconnect every minute?

Tags: raspberry-pi, service-worker, pusher, pusher-js

my website refreshs let's say every 5 minutes and I use a service worker. Inside this service worker I use pusher.com and this happens:

[image: Pusher Log]

There are many "Connection" and "Disconnection" events for only two Clients (Raspberry Pi). After this "Vacated" event there is no re-subscription.

Here is what every site does:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) { // Make sure sw are supported
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('/sw.js')
        .then(reg => {
          console.log('Service Worker: Registered');
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(`Service Worker: Error: ${err}`));
    });
}
```

And this happens only once (and not on activating) in service worker:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('web-' + channel);
const swListener = new BroadcastChannel('swListener');

channel.bind('foo', function() {
    self.foo();
});
```

If I run this code above on every page request everything get worse.

Did I something wrong? Is there a way to check my actual subscriptions in my service worker?